# Why does removing duplicates from a list produce [None, None] output?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I'm not able to understand why I am getting the results with **None** values.

```
#Remove duplicate items from a list
def remove_duplicates(list):
    unique_list = []
    return [unique_list.append(item) for item in list if item not in unique_list]
print remove_duplicates([1,1,2,2]) -> result [None, None]
```

When I print the result it shows the following: [None, None]

PS: I've seen other solutions and also aware of the list(set(list)) but I am trying to understand why the above result with integers gives [None, None] output.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do: `return list(set(list))` ?

Comment: because your statement returns a list with the return values of `unique_list.append(item)` which is `None`

Comment: BTW, do *not* use `list` as a variable name, it is a [builtin function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list)!

Comment: **Thank you** for all your answers

Answer (score 3):

Although using a [set is the proper way](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), the problem with your code, as the comments indicated, is that you are not actually returning `unique_list` from your function, you are returning the result of the list comprehension.

```
def remove_duplicates(my_list):
    unique_list = []
    do = [unique_list.append(item) for item in my_list if item not in unique_list]
    return unique_list  # Actually return the list!

print remove_duplicates([1,1,2,2]) -> result [1, 2]
```

Here I simply made a throwaway variable `do` that is useless, it just "runs" the comprehension. Understand?

That comprehension is storing a value each time you call `unique_list.append(item)` ... and that value is the result of the `append` method, which is `None`! So `do` equals `[None, None]`.

However, your `unique_list` *is* in fact being populated correctly, so we can return that and now your function works as expected.

Of course, this is not a normal use for a list comprehension and really weird.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using an assignment to the unused variable `do` ?

Comment: The goal being to make it clear that the variable is useless and not the desired output. I wanted to imply that the statement was being "executed" but the result isn't being used.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should upvote this answer for the good catch that he wasn't returning `unique_list` or to downvote because of the poor mistake you've done with `do` (which is really unnecessary, the comprehension will run without an assignment as well).

Comment: Well, the question was "why is the function return [None, None]", so ... hard to say. ;) I'll add a link to sets documentation.

Comment: You could just write `_ = […]` if you really wanted to put a variable there.

Comment: **Thank you** it really helped me understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that the method `list.append` returns None. You can test this easily with the following code:

```
myList=[1, 2, 3]
print myList.append(4)
```

So, a solution for you would issue would be

```
def remove_duplicates(myList):
    alreadyIncluded = []
    return [item for item in myList if item not in alreadyIncluded and not alreadyIncluded.append(item)]
print remove_duplicates([1,1,2,2])
```

The idea is that you will begin with an empty list of aldeady included elements and you will loop over all the elements in list, including them in the `alreadyIncluded` list. The `not` is necessary because the `append` will return `None` and `not None` is `True`, so the if will not be affected by the inclusion.

You were including a list of the result of the appends (always `None`), but what you need is a list of the elements that passed the `if` test.

I hope it helps.

Comment: **Thank you** rLinden for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have explained, the reason you're getting a list of `None` values is because `list.append` returns `None`, and you're calling it in a list comprehension. That means you're building a list full of `None` values along side your list of unique values.

I would like to suggest that you ditch the list comprehension. Because you need to access outside state (the list of unique values seen so far), a comprehension can't easily do what you want. A regular `for` loop is much more appropriate:

```
def remove_duplicates(lst):
    unique_list = []
    for item in lst:
        if item not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(item)
    return unique_list
```

A more Pythonic approach however would be to use a `set` to handle the unique items, and to make your function a generator:

```
def remove_duplicates(lst):
    uniques = set()
    for item in lst:
        if item not in unique_list:
            yield item
            uniques.add(item)
```

The `itertools.ifilterfase` function from the standard library can help improve this even further, as shown in the [recipe in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) (you'll have to scroll down a little to find the specific recipe):

```
def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    if key is None:
        for element in filterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
    else:
        for element in iterable:
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen_add(k)
                yield element
```

Comment: **Thank you** BlckKnght for the different solutions.